# MySql - Select value with datetime = datetime-3 minuts

Tags: mysql

I have a table with with 3 fields : id (*int 11*), user (*varchar 255*) and data (*DATETIME*).

I need somethings like :

```
SELECT user FROM counter WHERE date>'ACTUAL DATA - 3 MINUTS'
```

So i can return all username with data between the *actual data - 3 minuts* and the *actual data*. Like return all username between **2010-12-22 18:32:00** and **2010-12-22 18:35:00**

How can I do it with MySql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the [SUBTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime) function.

`SELECT user FROM counter WHERE date > SUBTIME( 'yourdate', '0:03' );`

**EDIT**

Since you changed your question here is an updated answer:

`SELECT user FROM counter WHERE date BETWEEN SUBTIME( 'yourdate', '0:03' ) and 'yourdate'`

Comment: Uhmn, i think this doesnt change, because as "yourdate" i pass the actual date (I get it with PHP). Looks that it works ;)

Comment: In that case, don't get the date from php, substitute `'yourdate'` with `NOW()`

Comment: What's the difference in your opinion about put the PHP variable with date or call NOW()?

Comment: It is cleaner. You can setup mysql to use different date types depending on your locale. If you use `NOW()` you don't have to construct and format a date in php at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user FROM counter WHERE date > DATE_SUB(dateColumn, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user FROM counter WHERE date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE AND NOW()
```